# Is it possible to allow edits on self-deleted posts by high rep users?

Tags: feature-request, edits, deleted-questions

I posted [a question with a very detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165665/force-a-vector-to-be-monotonically-increasing). After it was created, I realised that while the question was valid, it was not what I wanted and substantial edits had to be made.

To not waste anyone's time, I deleted the question. To my surprise, I cannot edit the question anymore.

Thus, if it is not possible to allow edits on deleted posts, how should I change the content of my question? Should I temporarily undelete the post, copy any code required, then delete it, and create a new post? Or should I just enter edit mode while the question is open for viewing by the public?

In response to the comment that I should be able to edit my deleted question, on my screen the edit button is greyed out. The only option is to share/close/undelete/flag:

[image]

I then went through and undeleted it, then deleted it, and then I could click the edit button, but this resulted:

[image]

Click refresh after this greys out the edit option.

As explained in the comments and the linked post, this is to stop question abuse. Thus I am slightly changing the question posed in this post. Since I am a relatively high rep user, I am less likely to be trying to question abuse by using the delete function.

So, can people like me edit our own deleted posts when a genuine mistake has been made? Or maybe, allow edits on posts deleted within 5 minutes of it being posted?

Comment: You should be able to edit your own deleted question, even in deleted state.

Comment: I can't click the edit option,

Comment: I can share, close, undelete, or flag. But not edit.

Comment: Strange thing, even I  could edit it :-P ... Caching issue?

Comment: strange, this sounds like a bug then? I have reproduced it now.

Comment: That's strange. I can confirm I can edit your question too. You definitely should be able to do that as well.

Comment: I logged in from a private browser window and I still cannot edit it.

Comment: Thanks, the answer there provides a work around on how to get around this problem.

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah, interesting. I wasn't aware of that policy.

Comment: actually it doesn't solve my problem as I can't work out how to look at the source without undeleting it.

Comment: @Alex: URL-hacking: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35165665/revisions

Comment: `posts/POST_ID/revisions`

Comment: this is all very bothersome in order to fix a mistake I made in posting. I have revised my question to ask for an exception for myself :)

Comment: I'm predicting a status-declined tag will be added to this post in the near future. Either that, or a status-bydesign tag.

Comment: Don't think so @tiny, how about both?

Comment: I've never seen both on one question before, but I suppose there is a first for everything @Deduplicator